# ZMQ via C# - clrzmq binding Windows XP fails but is OK on Win7

Tags: c#, zeromq

I have been been developing a platform using ZMQ (2.2) as the main communications layer.  Earlier this week I decided to take the advice on the zeromq website and upgrade to the latest stable build 3.2.2

However after going through the pain of updating to the new API I was seriously disappointed to discover that there seems to be a problem with the clrzmq binding in that it fails to load the libzmq library on Windows XP (SP3) machines. I keep getting a SEHException exception?!

I was just wondering if anyone out there has had the same problem and if there is a workaround (or even better a fix) for it?

Cheers
:)

**EDIT**
Just to clarify, the library is loaded fine, I know this because the context is created without any issue.  The problem occurs when the CreateSocket method is called on the context... see code snippet below

```
        ZmqContext context = ZmqContext.Create();

        ZmqSocket socket = context.CreateSocket(SocketType.REQ);
```

After adding tracing as suggested by Jakob, I get the following output

```
Assertion failed: Connection refused (..\..\..\src\signaler.cpp:310)
```

Any Ideas what this means?

**EDIT**
I should also mention that this issue **does not** happen on all the XP machines, **only some of them**.  I have been trying to figure out what the difference is between the machines that work and the ones that don't.  Without knowing this it would be far too risky to upgrade and release into a production environment.

Comment: Have you tried switching on the tracing for clrzmq to see if it reports any details about the failed load? Check out tracing options here: https://github.com/zeromq/clrzmq#tracing

Comment: @Jakob - I've tried to to this but for some reason I am not getting any trace output from the library? I have uploaded a small sample on my skydrive (http://sdrv.ms/12vkVxG)

Comment: @Jakob - I think I've been staring at the screen to too long!!! I do get some trace back from the library (see main body).

Comment: The code compiles ok and it runs without any exceptions on my machine (although the firewall complained a bit, which is normal). Added a longer answer with some more ideas.

Comment: @Jakob - First of all, thank you for taking the time to look over this. You are completely right in you answer when you say that it doesn't make sense to bind a REQ to a wildcard.  When I knocked up the sample project I just arbitrarily picked a socket type.

Comment: continued - My problem is not the Bind method (although if the CreateSocket method worked it, the next line would probably fail due to a bad binding expression). Actually, it doesn't seem to matter which socket type I choose, the CreateSocket method always fails!? I have tried running this example on a a few XP boxes. It runs on some of them and not on others!!

Comment: Hm, tricky, I do not have any more ideas at the moment, will get back if I come up with something. If you find a solution or find the problem, please add some info, it would be interesting to know since I plan to deploy some ZeroMq code on a bunch of XP machines in the future.

Comment: Just an idea, make sure you are running clrzmq against the latest (stable) zmqlib, i.e. 3.2.2. The default nuget package may be set up to use an older version (3.0.0 or so). There may be some bugs that have been fixed.

Comment: @JakobMöllås, any ideas where to pick up the .Net bindings for version 3.2.2, both for clrzmq and libzmq? I cannot find them anywhere, certainly not on Nuget. Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: @MattWolf Yes, the source & project is located at Github, [here](https://github.com/zeromq/clrzmq) and the Nuget package can be found [here](http://packages.nuget.org/Packages/clrzmq). Note that the Nuget package version info is not up to date but you can modify the nuget package config to get a version matching 3.2.2.

Comment: @JakobMöllås, the nuget library you referenced shows it is version 3.0.0rc1 which I tried and seems to be suffering from quite a number glitches.

Comment: @JakobMöllås, Hi Jacob, just a quick follow-up question because you seem to be the expert on ZeroMQ: I have a ROUTER that binds and a DEALERS that connect to this ROUTER. How can I ensure that messages sent to the ROUTER will be dropped and not queued if the DEALER does not exist anymore but still messages are routed through ROUTER with the DEALER.IDENTITY?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the example you provided, you are binding to a **REQ** socket (Request, i.e. client socket), and also binding the REQ socket using wildcards. I am not sure how this will play out, but to me it does not make sense. I do not think this is supported but I cannot find or remember any documentation about binding to a REQ socket. Likely strange things will happen.

The **REP** (response) socket is the "server" end of a REQ/REP setup (request/response), where you `bind` the server side using a REP socket to an endpoint, either explicitly specified "tcp://127.0.0.1:5555" or using wildcards, e.g. "all interfaces", "tcp://*:5555". The client side would then `connect` using a REQ socket to an explicit endpoint address, "tcp://127.0.0.1:5555", no wildcards.

The server would do this:

```
ZmqContext context = ZmqContext.Create();
ZmqSocket socket = context.CreateSocket(SocketType.REP);
socket.Bind("tcp://*:5501");
```

And the client this:

```
ZmqContext context = ZmqContext.Create();
ZmqSocket socket = context.CreateSocket(SocketType.REQ);
socket.Connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:5501");
```

Apart from those issues, you should also make sure the firewall is not blocking and make sure the port is not already in use (using for example the NETSTAT command).

For ZeroMq addressing rules, see the [zmq_tcp API documentation](http://api.zeromq.org/3-2%3azmq-tcp), and for the socket, see the [zmq_socket API documentation](http://api.zeromq.org/3-2%3azmq-socket).